# prototype inheritance is wrong

Tags: javascript, prototype

I created a person constructor and I take a `firstname = fn`, and `lastname = ln`, and `dateofbirth = dob`.

That Code is :

```
function Person(fn, ln, dob){
    this.fn = fn;
    this.ln = ln;
    this.dob = new Date(dob);
}
```

and also I added prototype

```
Person.prototype.calcAge = function(){
    const diff = Date.now() - this.dob.getTime();
    const age = new Date(diff);
    return Math.abs(age.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

This is my first Person constructor.

and second constructor i am taken as a customer constructor and that code is :

```
function Customer(fn,ln,phone,membership){
    Person.call(this,fn,ln);
    this.phone = phone;
    this.membership = membership;

}
```

And I am inheriting prototype from person to customer

```
//Inheriting Person Prototype
Customer.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

// Making Customer Prototype
Customer.prototype.constructor = Customer;
```

And i am console logging :

```
const Customer1 = new Customer('Sairam', 'Gudiputis', '790-139-7848', 'Premium');
console.log(Customer1)
```

but in console i am getting invalid date of birth that i am not used in customer..

```js
    function Person(fn, ln, dob){
     this.fn = fn;
     this.ln = ln;
     this.dob = new Date(dob);
    }
 
  Person.prototype.calcAge = function(){
     const diff = Date.now() - this.dob.getTime();
     const age = new Date(diff);
     return Math.abs(age.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
    }
 
 function Customer(fn,ln,phone,membership){
     Person.call(this,fn,ln);
     this.phone = phone;
     this.membership = membership;
    
    }
 
 //Inheriting Person Prototype
    Customer.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
    
    // Making Customer Prototype
    Customer.prototype.constructor = Customer;
 
 const Customer1 = new Customer('Sairam', 'Gudiputis', '790-139-7848', 'Premium');
    console.log(Customer1)
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsfiddle or a codepen?

Comment: Sure Just hold on

Comment: I've added it for you @DavidPrinve

Comment: You are not passing any date to `Person.call(this,fn,ln)` So, `dob` parameter is `undefined`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sairamgudiputis/fdcpaqt9/3

Comment: This is JS fiddle i putted please find it

Comment: *"but in console i am getting invalid date"* you don't pass `dob`, therefore `dob` is undefined. `new Date(undefined)` creates an `Invalid Date`.

Comment: @adiga i dont want dob on customer i want that on person only...

Comment: @DavidPrinve that's inheritance. Everything that `Person` has is part of `Customer`.

*"guys in person constructor i want dob, in customer i dont want dob "* that's like saying `People` have legs, but `Customers` *(which are People)* do not.

Comment: guys in person constructor i want dob, in customer i dont want dob

Comment: Thats i given in Person.call(this,fn,ln) ONLY

Comment: Every `Customer` is a `Person`

Comment: Custemer construction does not take any dob. Dob is undefined. You can either modify customer construction to allow dob parameter and pass it to Person or wrape `this.dob = new Date(dob)` statement in If(dob) condition

Comment: @vipulpatel brother in person constructor i want ` firstname = fn`,  `lastname = ln`, `date of birth = dob`,
These values i want in person..

when it comes to customer i want `firstname and lastname` along with `phone and membership`.

Comment: You getting error because you don't pass any value for the dob in the call Person.call(this,fn,ln); so the value of the dob is null and the this.dob = new Date(dob); is receiving null value

Comment: @Sairam.Gudiputis that's what i am telling. As you do not want dob in customer creation, newDate(dob) is getting called with undefined dob which is causing error. So wrap tjay line. `if(dob) { this.dob = new Date(dob) }` Thus in case lf customer creation without dob this statement wont get executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `dob` in `Customer`, add:

```
      if (!(this instanceof Customer)) {
          this.dob = new Date(dob);
      }
```

in `Person` constructor:

```js
function Person(fn, ln, dob){
     this.fn = fn;
     this.ln = ln;
      if (!(this instanceof Customer)) {
       this.dob = new Date(dob);
      }
    }
 
  Person.prototype.calcAge = function(){
     const diff = Date.now() - this.dob.getTime();
     const age = new Date(diff);
     return Math.abs(age.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
    }
 
 function Customer(fn,ln,phone,membership){
     Person.call(this,fn,ln);
     this.phone = phone;
     this.membership = membership;
    
    }
 
 //Inheriting Person Prototype
    Customer.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
    
    // Making Customer Prototype
    Customer.prototype.constructor = Customer;
 
 const Customer1 = new Customer('Sairam', 'Gudiputis', '790-139-7848', 'Premium');
    console.log(Customer1)
```